# Phython: How to continue to to request for input after a valid one is added?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
my_names = []
while len(my_names) < 2:
    my_name = input("Enter a name: ").strip().lower()
    if my_name == "":
        print("Minimum 2 names.")
        continue  # Continue to prompt for names
    elif my_name in my_names:
        print("No duplicate name...re-enter")
        continue  # Continue to prompt for names
    else:
        my_names.append(my_name)
        print(my_names)
        continue  # Continue to prompt for names
```

I'm a beginner python programmer. My objective is to get user to input more than 2 values and the value cannot be a duplicate of those already in the list. After I get to the last else clause, my quote exits even though I have a 'continue'. Why is this so? How can I do it such that only after the list of names has more than 2 values, and user enters empty value, the while loop then exits?

I tried playing around with nested ifs but doesn't seem to work. Without the continue also doesn't work. Thought of using elif instead of else but I don't know what other expression i can be as the clause. Tried to ask AI code creators also can't get the result I want. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your script works just fine. 
If you want to exit after three names change this `while len(my_names) < 3`

Comment: It stopped until only 2 names. I want it to continue typing more names, minimum is 2, but no maximum, until user presses <enter>, (ie, no value, but must be after more than 2 names).

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you should change your code like this:

```
my_names = []
while True:
    my_name = input("Enter a name: ").strip().lower()
    if my_name == "":
        if len(my_names) <= 2:
            print("Minimum 2 names.")
            continue  # Continue to prompt for names
        else:
            break  # Exit Loop
    elif my_name in my_names:
        print("No duplicate name...re-enter")
        continue  # Continue to prompt for names
    else:
        my_names.append(my_name)
        print(my_names)
        continue  # Continue to prompt for names
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would satisfy you?:

```py
my_names = []

finished = False
while not finished:
    my_name = input("Enter a name: ").strip().lower()
    if my_name == "":
        finished = len(my_names) >= 2
        if not finished:
            print("Minimum 2 names.")
    elif my_name in my_names:
        print("No duplicate name… re-enter")
    else:
        my_names.append(my_name)
        print(my_name, "added")
```